# Ruby on Rails 3, Changing Views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, listview, gridview, view

Im working with Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2.

I have a search page that will display a list of results in grid format. However, I want to be able to give the user an option to display them in **list format**.

Could anyone please advise me about how I can offer a change view option,and still keep the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not specified where query is stored,

I will hope that in url, like example.com/search?query=mylookupstring

So in this case all we need is to place somewhere on a page, link_to search path and pass your query + some parameter back to controller to prepare new view

```
 <%= link_to "List", search_some_thing_path(:query=>params[:query],:list=>true) %>
```

nice & easy

Post your details if i show bad skills with telepathy today.

UPDATE:

Pay attention to params & url. Yours & my example. You shouldn't just copy

as your controller expects params[:search] not params[:query]

So fix error in you link_to & move_on!

PS Great tip to find out how rails really work is to use [debugger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html).

You may attach it in view

`<% debugger %>` or in model/controller simply `debugger`

Don't forget to include debug gems in your Gemfile, smth like

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
```

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely correct in the fact that the search string is shown in the url. 

eg: http://127.0.0.1:3000/events?utf8=✓&search%5Btown_name_equals%5D=Leicester&search%5Bgenre_name_equals%5D=DJ+Music&search%5Bdate_equals%5D=&commit=Search

How would I set the controller to change the view? :S Sorry for the noobish question, but I'm still learning :(

Comment: add to EventsController search method condition like if params[:list] and render proper view according to your needs, for example render :list (supposing your have such view), else render :grid

Comment: I've got the switching between views down, but the problem is that it is not keeping my search results.

My view contains:

`<% if params[:list] %>
   
    <%= link_to "Grid View", events_path(:query=>params[:search],:list=>false), :class => 'uploadbutton', :style => 'float:right' %>`

and the events controller contains:



`def index
    @search = Event.search(params[:search])
    @events = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @number_of_events = @events.count
  
    if params[:list]
      render :list
    end
  end`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you check what I pasted in the comments, you'll see that I had already amended the view link_to to say params[:search], I asked the question because this did not work.

I know you are trying to help, I just don't want you to think I have no brain and am just a copy-n-paste kinda guy.
After I switch views: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/events?list=true&query[date_equals]=&query[genre_name_equals]=DJ+Music&query[town_name_equals]=`

Before view switch: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/events?utf8=✓&search%5Btown_name_equals%5D=&search%5Bgenre_name_equals%5D=Theatre&search%5Bdate_equals%5D=&commit=Search`

Comment: Obviously you have misunderstood me. My appeal to fix error was straight to not make feel stupid anybody. Anyway right solution is events_path(:search=>params[:search],:list=>false). As you can see we pass hash object to controller as params search is key, params[:search] acts as a value. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks very much :) It fixed the problem :D
Do you recommend any gems for searching in Rails 3. I'm using MetaSearch at the moment but I don't like all the search terms being displayed in the URL?

Comment: MetaSearch author has another gem for searching, newer one. You may check it at github. Newer version does not solve query in url issue, however I think it is not a problem at all. It may be useful for user, as it is bookmarkable & shareable.